# Intersection of multiple dataframes in r with respect to rows or samples

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a many frames, some of the ids or column names in them are the same. I want to merge all the dataframes in a single dataframe but only for samples that are present in all the dataframes. In other words, I want the intersection of samples in a new dataframe. For example First data frame (df1) looks like

```
       m1      m2     m3
P001   60.00   2.0     1
P002   14.30   2.077   1
P003   29.60   2.077   1.4
P004   10.30   2.077   1.3
P005   79.30   2.077   3.1
P006   79.30   2.077   3.1
P008    9.16   2.077   2.2
```

and the second data frame (df2) looks like

```
patid  n1      n2   n3
P001   12.00   2.0   1
P003   17.60   1.7   1
P005   22.30   2.7   1
P006   26.30   1.7   1
```

Similarly third dataframe

```
patid  k2      k3   k4
P001   8.00   2.0   1.7
P004   9.60   1.7   1.8
P005   7.30   2.7   2.1
P008   6.30   1.7   1.9
P008   6.38   1.78  1.92
```

I want to have a fourth dataframe that has intersection of all the samples in that dataframe. The samples in that dataframe in that data frame will be for eg P001 and P005.

The answer could be something like this

```
       m1      m2     m3      n1      n2    n3    k2     k3    k4
P001   60.00   2.0     1      12.00   2.0   1     8.00   2.0   1.7
P005   79.30   2.077   3.1    22.30   2.7   1     7.30   2.7   2.1
```

The longer option would be to use loops. A nested matches such as

```
matchmicSer <- df2[match(rownames(df1), df2$patid)]

matchserMic <- df1[match(df2$patid,rownames(df1))]
```

and continue but but I am sure R should have a shortcut. Merge would not be an option because some of the variables patid in second and third dataframe may have duplicates, like P008 in thrid dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the example showed, the first dataset ('df1') didn't have 'patid' column.  So, created the column from the 'rownames'.

```
df1$patid <- row.names(df1)
```

We can use `Reduce` with `merge` after placing the datasets in a 'list' (`mget(paste0('df', 1:3))`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='patid'), mget(paste0('df', 1:3)))
#  patid   m1    m2  m3   n1  n2 n3  k2  k3  k4
#1  P001 60.0 2.000 1.0 12.0 2.0  1 8.0 2.0 1.7
#2  P005 79.3 2.077 3.1 22.3 2.7  1 7.3 2.7 2.1
```

#### Update

Regarding the duplicate `patid`s , in the 'df3', there is a duplicate ('P008'), but it is not present in all the datasets (so not found in the output).  Suppose, if we have a 'patid' that is present in all the datasets and is duplicated in one of them

```
 df3$patid[2] <- 'P001'
 Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='patid'), mget(paste0('df', 1:3)))
 #  patid   m1    m2  m3   n1  n2 n3  k2  k3  k4
 #1  P001 60.0 2.000 1.0 12.0 2.0  1 8.0 2.0 1.7
 #2  P001 60.0 2.000 1.0 12.0 2.0  1 9.6 1.7 1.8
 #3  P005 79.3 2.077 3.1 22.3 2.7  1 7.3 2.7 2.1
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(m1 = c(60, 14.3, 29.6, 10.3, 79.3, 79.3, 9.16), 
 m2 = c(2, 2.077, 2.077, 2.077, 2.077, 2.077, 2.077), m3 = c(1, 
 1, 1.4, 1.3, 3.1, 3.1, 2.2)), .Names = c("m1", "m2", "m3"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("P001", "P002", "P003", 
 "P004", "P005", "P006", "P008"))

df2 <-  structure(list(patid = c("P001", "P003", "P005", "P006"),
 n1 = c(12, 17.6, 22.3, 26.3), n2 = c(2, 1.7, 2.7, 1.7), n3 = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("patid", "n1", "n2", "n3"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df3 <- structure(list(patid = c("P001", "P004", "P005", "P008",
 "P008"), k2 = c(8, 9.6, 7.3, 6.3, 6.38), k3 = c(2, 1.7, 2.7, 1.7,
 1.78), k4 = c(1.7, 1.8, 2.1, 1.9, 1.92)), .Names = c("patid", "k2", 
 "k3", "k4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: What if the columns are not unique? i.e. what if the patid has dubplicates as in third dataframe

Comment: @lovedynasty My code was based on the example you provided.  Please update your post with the additional cases and expected result.

Comment: The duplicate was mentioned in the example and your structure df3 contains P008 twice. When I run this I get an error 
   
    Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: @lovedynasty Based on the `dput` output I used, I am not getting any error.  Have you tried the first line `df1$patid <- row.names(df1)` before `Reduce`  If I don't create the `patid` column in `df1`, I get the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a function to perform *batch joins* which address your question.
Using the data produced by akrun:

```r
library(data.table) # devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")
dt1 <- as.data.table(df1, keep.rownames = "patid")
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
dt3 <- as.data.table(df3)

library(dwtools) # devtools::install_github("jangorecki/dwtools")
joinbyv(dt3, list(dt2, dt1), by = list("patid","patid"), nomatch = list(0L,0L))
#    patid   m1    m2  m3   n1  n2 n3  k2  k3  k4
# 1:  P001 60.0 2.000 1.0 12.0 2.0  1 8.0 2.0 1.7
# 2:  P005 79.3 2.077 3.1 22.3 2.7  1 7.3 2.7 2.1
```

Of course if you don't want to have a new dependency ([dwtools](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools)) in your code you can define simple `joinbyv` function as:

```r
joinbyv <- function(master, join, by, nomatch){
    joinby <- function(master, join, by, nomatch){
        setkeyv(join,by)
        if(!identical(key(master),key(join))) setkeyv(master,key(join))
        join[master, nomatch = nomatch]
    }
    for(i in 1:length(join)){
        master <- joinby(master = master, join[[i]], by[[i]], nomatch[[i]])
    }
    master
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to keep all observations of shared IDs which are duplicated within some tables.

I write in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) #1.9.5+
setDT(df1,keep.rownames="patid",key="patid")
setDT(df2,key="patid")
setDT(df3,key="patid")

df4<-df1[df2][df3,nomatch=0L]
```