# Merging more than two data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am trying to merge:

```
r <- merge(Join10Table, Join90Table, Join40Table, by=EmployeeNumber)
```

I have more than 100 tables
but R doesn't allow. Any way?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list. You also need to quote the variable passed to the `by` argument.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478584/intersection-of-multiple-dataframes-in-r-with-respect-to-rows-or-samples